# Got my external NetStream working - but how to load an .flv from my library?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video

How do I load an .flv (lets call it "library.flv") sitting in my (internal) Flash library into my Netstream?

I can easily load external .flv's with the below, but I need to load the .flv from my library

```
//Creating the video object
var ADFvideo = new Video(110,180);
videoContainer.addChild(ADFvideo);
ADFvideo.x = 0;
ADFvideo.y = 0;

//Loading the flv into the video object 
var ADFnc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
ADFnc.connect(null);
var ADFns:NetStream = new NetStream(ADFnc);
ADFvideo.attachNetStream(ADFns);

//Handling metaData (it arrives as the video starts playing, so it is the pefect time to fire the first event);
var ADFcustomClient:Object = new Object();
ADFcustomClient.onMetaData = ADFmetaDataHandler;
ADFns.client = ADFcustomClient;
var ADFinfoObj:Object;
function ADFmetaDataHandler(ADFinfo:Object):void
{
        //meta stuff
}

ADFns.play("files/external.flv"); /* current way of loading the external .flv */

ADFns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, statusChanged);

function statusChanged(stats:NetStatusEvent)
{
        //event changes
}
```

Comment: You can't play FLV from the library. You have to embed it with code. But the result is the same, a new `Class` of the item but instead of new instance going to `Stage` or `MovieClip` it goes into a `ByteArray` that is then appended to `NetStream` for playback. See my answer below..

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use NetStream with an embedded flv video. When you import the video to your library, you will have the option to convert it to a movieclip or to keep it as a simple video that will sit on the timeline. For the later option, you can't create an AS Linkage. It is not recommended for longer clip as you will experience syncronisation issue, playback problem and pre-loading issues.

Comment: I did try with the approach you describe, where I dragged to .flv to the library and converted it to a movieclip, but even with my small 5kb file, I experienced sluggish behaviour, so looking for a way that I can load the .flv into a movieclip, like I do with the NetStream.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this adjustment of your posted code as a starting point.. Tested using 3-second video (H.263 / Sorenson) of 1280 width by 720 height with 44100hz 128 MP3 sound and there was no "..experiencing sluggish behaviour" on my side with a crappy testing machine.

When the video ends you need to use your function `statusChanged(stats:NetStatusEvent)` to handle what happens next (I've edited the code to do constant replays as example)

Anyway this code means the final compiled SWF and FLV exist as one package. So a 200kb FLV will add +200kb to the output SWF size. Just bear in mind especially with large / multiple FLV embeds.

```
//// Specify embed item and create Class to store such item
[ Embed(source = "yourFileName.flv", mimeType = "application/octet-stream") ]
var bytes_FLV : Class; 
//// End embedded item setup

//create bytes for NStream from embedded item
var file_BA:ByteArray = new bytes_FLV(); 

//Creating the video object
var ADFvideo = new Video(110,180);
videoContainer.addChild(ADFvideo);
ADFvideo.x = 0;
ADFvideo.y = 0;

//Loading the flv into the video object 
var ADFnc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
ADFnc.connect(null);
var ADFns:NetStream = new NetStream(ADFnc);
ADFvideo.attachNetStream(ADFns);

//Handling metaData (it arrives as the video starts playing, so it is the pefect time to fire the first event);
var ADFcustomClient:Object = new Object();
ADFcustomClient.onMetaData = ADFmetaDataHandler;
ADFns.client = ADFcustomClient;
var ADFinfoObj:Object;
function ADFmetaDataHandler(ADFinfo:Object):void
{
        //meta stuff
}

///ADFns.play("files/external.flv"); /* current way of loading the external .flv */

//Send file_BA to NStream for playback.. 
ADFns.play(null);
ADFns.appendBytesAction(NetStreamAppendBytesAction.RESET_BEGIN);        
ADFns.appendBytes(file_BA);

ADFns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, statusChanged);

function statusChanged(stats:NetStatusEvent)
{
    //event changes
    //trace("NetStream Status : " + stats.info.code);

    if (stats.info.code == "NetStream.Buffer.Empty") 
    { 
        //Buffer.Empty = video has ended..
        ADFns.appendBytesAction(NetStreamAppendBytesAction.RESET_BEGIN);        
        ADFns.appendBytes(file_BA);

    }
}
```